# Azure SQL Database: Full text index on certain emails does not work

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a full text index defined on user table's username column. When there is any character following + symbol in email in the search query there is no result. + is a valid symbol in email. Appreciate if you can explain why I see this behavior and any workaround for this.

```
/* returns result */
select * from AspNetUsers where contains(username, '"foo+77@gmail.com*"')
select * from AspNetUsers where contains(username, '"foo+*"')

/* does not return result */
select * from AspNetUsers where contains(username, '"foo+77*"')
select * from AspNetUsers where contains(username, '"foo+7*"')
select * from AspNetUsers where contains(username, '"foo+77@gmail*"')
```

Comment: Full text indexes aren't really designed for email addresses; I wouldn't expect it to work as you expect. `+` is going to be seen as a stopword. Considering that you are looking at the prefix anyway, I would suggest using a `LIKE` as it'll be SARGable; a `LIKE` is only non-SARGable when it has a leading wild card.

Comment: can you explain what you are logically trying do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding backslash before character `7` returns results.

Before adding backslash `\` in the query:

[image]

After adding backslash \ in the query:

QUERY:

```
select * from AspNetUsers where contains(username, '"foo+\77*"')
select * from AspNetUsers where contains(username, '"foo+\7*"')
select * from AspNetUsers where contains(username, '"foo+\77@gmail*"')
```

[image]